# Cannot create inner bean 'org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass

Tags: spring, rest, exception, compiler-errors, javabeans

I have exception type: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
full stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass#1e222db' of type [org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass] while setting bean property 'defaultViews' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass] for bean with name 'org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass#1e222db' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
```

my dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="org.szymon.email.*" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<mvc:annotation-driven />                                       

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            <entry key="jsonp" value="application/javascript"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView"/>
            <bean class="org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

and my MyMapperClass:

```
package org.szymon.email.classes;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView;

public class MyMapperClass extends MappingJacksonJsonView {

    /**
     * Default content type. Overridable as bean property.
     */
    public static final String DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/javascript";

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the view given the specified model, merging it with static
     * attributes and a RequestContext attribute, if necessary.
     * Delegates to renderMergedOutputModel for the actual rendering.
     * @see #renderMergedOutputModel
     */
    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        if("GET".equals(request.getMethod().toUpperCase())) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();

            if(params.containsKey("callback")) {
                response.getOutputStream().write(new String(params.get("callback")[0] + "(").getBytes());
                super.render(model, request, response);
                response.getOutputStream().write(new String(");").getBytes());
                response.setContentType("application/javascript");
            }

            else {
                super.render(model, request, response);
            }
        }

        else {
            super.render(model, request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

This is continuation of solving problem from question:
 [Spring RESTful ajax gets error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031728/solved-spring-restful-ajax-gets-error)

There is one more interesting thing.
When I put comment on this bean like this:

```
<!-- <bean class="org.szymon.email.classes.MyMapperClass"/> -->
```

And create instance of this class in method on my controller and invoke render method of it, then everything is fine... but it is not proper solution.

Please help.
Cheers

Comment: It seems that MyMapperClass is not on the classpath. Is it in some other jar that you have failed to include?

Comment: This is class from my package org.szymon.email.classes in my project, created by myself, I'm using eclipse.

Comment: Weird... Do you have your code posted in GitHub or something so myself and other users can take a look?

Comment: I will post it on git, just give me some time...

Comment: link to github: https://github.com/szymonzakrzewski/mailservice

Comment: First of all, the code will not compile. You have `import com.szymon.mailservice.concrete.MappingJacksonJsonpView;` in `MailController`, but `MappingJacksonJsonpView` does not exist

Comment: I think however that it is safe to remove the import

Comment: I just clone project from github.. and it is different then my... give me some time and I will post again after I will fix it

Comment: Ok, take your time :)

Comment: Done :) can you clone it again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a build - IDE related. I was able to run the project both from IntellIJ IDEA and also by executing then Maven build and placing the produced war in `webapps` directory of Tomcat.

I suggest you do a Maven clean-compile-package and try again

Comment: I did, right click on project > run as > maven clean (in eclipse kepler) then I try to run it on glassfish 4 and still same error :(

Comment: I don't have glassfish, so I can't help you out there, but I strongly believe that there is something wrong with your build. Like I said it works like a charm in Tomcat

Comment: Good! That is another question, so either accept the answer to this one (so future users will know that the solution is correct) and start a new one with the new problem, or just delete this question and start a new one